# How can I trigger the function using the button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

my code consists of a select by provinces, when I click the province to filter I get the result of clinics in that province, what I want is to get that result by clicking the button, not through the select itself.///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select, { SingleValue } from 'react-select'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import "./Modal.css";

interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean,
    closeModal: () => void
}


export const SearchFilterClinics : React.FC<Props> = ({ children, isOpen, closeModal,  }) => {

         ////filter

         type OptionType = {
            value: string;
            label: string;
          };
    
          
            const provincesList: OptionType[] = [
                { value: 'Todos', label: 'Todos' },
                { value: 'Valencia', label: 'Valencia' },
                { value: 'Alicante', label: 'Alicante' },
                { value: 'Castellón', label: 'Castellón' },
               
            ]

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFilteredSelect, setClinicListFilteredSelect] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [filterSelectClinic, setFilterSelectClinic] = useState<SingleValue<OptionType>>(provincesList[0]);

    const handleChangeSelect = async (provinceList:  SingleValue<OptionType>) => {
        getClinic().then((response) => {
            setClinicList(response);
            setClinicListFilteredSelect(response)
            setFilterSelectClinic(provinceList);
            filterSelect(provinceList );
          }).catch ((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });         
      }

       
      const filterSelect=(termSearch)=>{
        const resultFilterSelect = clinicList.filter((element) => {
          if(element.province?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.value.toLowerCase() )
        
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setClinicListFilteredSelect(resultFilterSelect);
      }

      const handleModalContainerClick = (e) => e.stopPropagation();

   

    return  (
                <>
                     <div className={`modal ${isOpen && "is-open"}`} onClick={closeModal}>
                         <div className="modal-container" onClick={handleModalContainerClick}>
                            <button className="modal-close" onClick={closeModal}>x</button>
                            {children}
                           
                            <div>
                                <h1>Encuentra tu clínica</h1>
                            </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <form>
                                        
                                        <label>Provincia</label>
                                            <Select 
                                                defaultValue={filterSelectClinic}
                                                options={provincesList}
                                                onChange={handleChangeSelect}
                                                />

                                        
                                                 <button onClick={handleChangeSelect}>buscar</button> 
                                    </form>


                                { 
                                  
                                    clinicListFilteredSelect.map((clinicFilter) => (
                                        <div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.title}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.propsPhone}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.mobile}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.email}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.province} </div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.registry}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                          
                </>
            )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the `handleChangeSelect` function with the button, and also when the select menu changes (with onChange). So remove the `onChange` in the select, and leave the `onClick` for the button.

```
<label>Provincia</label>
<Select 
    defaultValue={filterSelectClinic}
    options={provincesList}
    onChange={handleChangeSelect} //THIS TRIGGERS THE FUNCTION
 />

<button onClick={handleChangeSelect}>buscar</button> //ALSO TRIGGERS FUNCTION
```